# Excel XML: How to not export empty `<xs:complexType>` field?

Tags: excel, xml

I use the Excel Import/Export XML feature (from the developper tab) and i'm encountering an issue with exporting empty data.

I would like to not export a `<xs:complexType>` when values are empty. So like the `<xs:simpleType>` exporting behavior.

Here are my reproduction steps :

1. Create an `.XSD` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="myxsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="myxsd" version="1.0.0">

    <xs:complexType name="HeaderType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mySimple" type="my:MySimpleType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="myComplex" type="my:MyComplexType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="MyComplexType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="element2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="element3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="MySimpleType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="header" type="my:HeaderType" />

    <xs:element name="contents">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="my:header" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

2. Import this XSD as XML Source Mapping in Excel.
3. Add some data to the mapping table :
   [image: excel xml exporting issue]
4. Export to XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:contents xmlns:ns1="myxsd">
    <ns1:header>
        <mySimple>test</mySimple>
        <myComplex>
            <element1>test</element1>
            <element2>test</element2>
            <element3>test</element3>
        </myComplex>
    </ns1:header>
    <ns1:header>
        <mySimple>test</mySimple>
        <myComplex/>
    </ns1:header>
    <ns1:header>
        <myComplex>
            <element1>test</element1>
            <element2>test</element2>
            <element3>test</element3>
        </myComplex>
    </ns1:header>
    <ns1:header>
        <mySimple>test</mySimple>
        <myComplex>
            <element1>test</element1>
        </myComplex>
    </ns1:header>
    <ns1:header>
        <myComplex/>
    </ns1:header>
</ns1:contents>
```

5. Consate the result: when a `<xs:complexType>` is empty, my XML will still contain the  field whereas  (`<xs:simpleType>`) will disappear correctly

So how to reproduce this behavior for the `<xs:complexType>`?
I have tested several attributes but never got the expected result.

Regards,